# Get form property when an input with the same name exists

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

With this HTML I can use the method property to get the (implied) form action:

```
<form id="frm">
    <input name="foo" value="bar">
</form>

document.getElementById('frm').method // "get"
```

But when the form contains an input with the name *method* I get the input element instead of action:

```
<form id="frm">
    <input name="method" value="bar">
</form>

document.getElementById('frm').method // input element
```

I could use

```
document.getElementById('frm').getAttribute('method') || "GET"
```

But I wonder if there is a nice way to get the (implied) method by using the property as in the first example?

Or is there a way to say: ignore named form inputs when accessing form properties?

Comment: `document.getElementById('frm').getAttribute('method') || "GET"` is the best way forward. Being explicit is always the 'nicest'